# When to use useEffect with no deps?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why and when should I useEffect if I have no deps?

What is the difference between (from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)):

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

And without useEffect?

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();

  ref.current = value;

  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: Well, in the second case you're just returning `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the two methods is that `useEffect` is run after the render cycle is complete and hence ref.current will hold the previous values whereas in the second method, your ref.current will be updated immediately and hence the previous will always be equal to the current value

Sample demo

```js
const {useRef, useEffect, useState} = React;
function usePreviousWithEffect(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();

  ref.current = value;

  return ref.current;
}
const App = () => {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   const previousWithEffect = usePreviousWithEffect(count);
   const previous = usePrevious(count);
   
   return (
      <div>
        <div>Count: {count}</div>
        <div>Prev Count with Effect: {previousWithEffect}</div>
        <div>Prev Count without Effect: {previous}</div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Also to answer your question, you pass `useEffect` without dependency when you want to perform some operation on each render. You however cannot set state or perform an action that will cause a re-render otherwise your app will go in a loop

Comment: but isn't set state will perform rerender anyway, thus causing loop anyway?

Comment: You aren't calling setState within useEffect so it won't go in a loop. Also if you look at the demo, useEffect is important so that the value is set only after the render and not before that otherwise it will just be the current value